# Create clickable links in terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome, guake

Is it possible to process/transform the output from `grep`
(or produce `grep`-like results, finding strings and/or patterns in files,
some other way) such that the search results
can be used as links (i.e., hyperlinks) to open an editor? 
I want to click on a `filename:line_number`
in my `grep` result and open my editor at the selected line.

```
$ grep "mServiceIntent" -R ./src/
./src/example/PhotoThumbnailFragment.java:67    private Intent mServiceIntent;
./src/example/PhotoThumbnailFragment.java:194        mServiceIntent =
./src/example/PhotoThumbnailFragment.java:203        getActivity().startService(mServiceIntent);
```

I know how to register protocols in the system to open the editor. 
For example, all URLs like `sblm://*` in my system open in Sublime Text. 
My question is: how to create custom links in guake terminal
(or maybe it doesn't depend on quake and works for default terminal program)?

Note: the related(?) question, [Is there a terminal app
that allows filenames to be clickable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63417/is-there-a-terminal-app-...),
is vague on specific implementation/solution details,
and doesn't explicitly mention my requirement
to jump directly to an identified line in the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a terminal app that allows filenames to be clickable?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63417/is-there-a-terminal-app-that-allows-filenames-to-be-clickable)

Answer (score 15):

Newer version of GNOME terminal now support hyperlinks with custom target via certain escape sequences. Try

```
echo -e '\e]8;;http://example.com\aThis is a link\e]8;;\a'
```

Opening these works the same way as described in the answer by Stephen Kitt.
To address the problem you described you could use a sed script (or some more advanced method) to translate the file names into hyperlinks. For me the following does the job (in bash and assuming the above way to create hyperlinks works)

```
grep "mServiceIntent" -R ./src/ | sed -e $'s#^\(.*\):#\e]8;;file:'`pwd`/$'\\1\a\\1\e]8;;\a#'
```

(I do not have sublime installed but most likely you can simply change file: into slbm:)

See also: https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda
(This is based on my answer at [Terminal - create hyperlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284476/terminal-create-hyperlinks/437581#437581))

Comment: See also https://purpleidea.com/blog/2018/06/29/hyperlinks-in-gnome-terminal/ for the `urlencode` bash function that makes things work correctly when you have spaces or other interesting characters in directory/file names.

Answer (score 0):

It's a computer; you can program it.  :-)

To make something "clickable" means either programming a GUI application or somehow using HTML.  The simplest way I can think of would be to generate an HTML page of HREFs, and pipe the output to, say, **lynx**, configuring the browser to open **emacs** appropriately.

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked - he does not want to reinvent the wheel by creating an entirely new terminal GUI.