# Terminal - create hyperlinks

Tags: gnome-terminal, url

I am creating Log-Reports which are viewable through the Web-browser. Is there an easy way to make links clickable in Linux Terminal? (Gnome-Terminal)

I am copying those links and manually open my web-browser to achieve that right now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the links are output as full URLs, they should be clickable when you hover over them (with the mouse pointer) while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> down.

Comment: @user1767754 Forthcoming gnome-terminal 3.26 will support web-style hyperlinks, that is, where the visible text is potentially something entirely different from the target URL. And there's even a patch for the `ls` utility. See https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda.

Comment: @ibrahim5253 yes, this is possible at least in Ubuntu. You just need to prepend `file://` to the fully qualified path of the file. Unfortunately, a relative path cannot be supplied, only a fully qualified path though.

Comment: This also works for macOS with the cmd key

Answer (score 45):

Newer version of GNOME terminal now support hyperlinks with custom target via certain escape sequences. Try

```
echo -e '\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\'
```

Opening these works the same way as described in the answer by Stephen Kitt.

See also: https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda