# With bash, create a hyperlink that opens with phpstorm

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, intellij

I have:

- a bash script running in terminal that gives me a list of files from my local computer
- phpstorm properly configured, so that I can open a file in phpstorm by typing
  "phpstorm /path/to/file" in terminal

Now I want the script to provide not only the list of filenames, but each filename should act as a link. Clicking on the link should have the same result as typing "phpstorm /path/to/file" in terminal.

I checked this answer [Terminal - create hyperlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284476/terminal-create-hyperlinks), but couldn't modify it to my needs.

This doesn't work at all:

```
echo -e '\e]8;;phpstorm /path/to/file\aLinktext\e]8;;\a'
```

This does something, but opens the file in gedit:

```
echo -e '\e]8;;file:///path/to/file\aLinktext\e]8;;\a'
```

I looks like I "only" have to switch the preferred editor to phpstorm... But how would I do that?

Any ideas?

Comment: I was wondering the same.